# How to limit file uploads by time on Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a rule to block a malicious user from updating their profile picture at a fast rate.

I found this example in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#updated)

```
// Allow reads if the resource was updated less than an hour ago
allow read: if resource.updated < request.time + duration.value(60, "m")
```

I want to do something similar, I want to allow the user to update the file only if an x amount of time has passed since the last update.

Let's say I don't want to let users update their profile pictures more than once every hour, I wrote this rule.

```
request.time >= resource.updated + duration.value(1, "h")
```

This rule is blocking the write every time, for testing proposes I was setting the duration to 10sec `duration.value(10, "s")` but even if I wait 10 min the upload still fails.

I'm not sure why this is not working, I know the problem is with this rule because everything works as expected when I remove it.

Here are my rules for `write`

```
allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                   // Only allow uploads once every hour
                   && request.time >= resource.updated + duration.value(1, "h")
                   // Require Authentication 
                   && request.auth != null && uid == request.auth.uid
                   // Don't allow anonymous users
                   && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous';
```

The docs don't show an example for writing, I begin wondering if this only works for `read`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to "<" instead of ">=" and use resource.data:

```
allow write: if request.time < resource.data.updatedAt + duration.value(1, 'h')
```

Comment: Using `resource.data.updatedAt` didn't work, I want to allow the update after x hours and not within x hours so >= is the correct condition. The firebase team confirmed that this was not possible at the firebase summit last year, but I was told that they would consider this as a feature request

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).